# PHP - Проверка строки на только ангийские или русские буквы (любые другие символы не буквы могут присутствовать)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, строки, проверка

Наверное для этого надо использовать функцию `preg_match`

Написал следующее:

- Для русских: `preg_match('/[А-Яа-яЁё]/iu', $text)`
- Для английских `preg_match('/[A-Za-z]/iu', $text)`

Нужна проверка например только русские и английские, и любые другие символы включая цифры пробелы и т.д.

Comment: Еще я так понял что арабские или китайские символы воспринимаются не как буквы их бы тоже исключить, только русский или только английские и цифры и символы

Comment: Так? `if (preg_match('~(?![a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ])\p{L}~u', $s)) { echo "Неверно!!!"; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну судя по вашему комментарию, вам нужно что-то типа такого:

```
$chr_en = "a-zA-Z0-9\s`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|:;<>?,.\/\"\'\\\[\]";
if (preg_match("/^[$chr_en]+$/", $string)) {
    //  TRUE
} else {
    //  FALSE
}
```

Результаты:

```
$string = 'Â english';      //  FALSE
$string = '!english 123';   //  TRUE
$string = 'en + рус';       //  FALSE
```

Для русского варианта, думаю справитесь :)

---

**Для EN**

```
$chr_en = "a-zA-Z0-9\s`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|:;<>?,.\/\"\'\\\[\]";
if (preg_match("/^[$chr_en]+$/", $string)) {
```

**Для RU**

```
$chr_ru = "А-Яа-яЁё0-9\s`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|:;<>?,.\/\"\'\\\[\]";
if (preg_match("/^[$chr_ru]+$/u", $string)) {
```

**Для RU + EN**

```
$chr_ru_en = "A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё0-9\s`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|:;<>?,.\/\"\'\\\[\]";
if (preg_match("/^[$chr_ru_en]+$/u", $string)) {
```